# Aggregate, sum and product of tuples in List

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Tuple<string, int>` :

```
"dog", 25
"cat", 5
"cat", 7
"rat", 4
"dog", 10
```

The rule of the Linq query I need must fulfill following: I need to have grouped tuples by the string value, but only if there are at least 2 occurrences. The aggregation for the grouped elements should be a multiplication. Afterall I need the sum of the aggregated elements. In the example above the result is 25*10 + 5*7 = 285.

So far I have tried this beside several other things:

```
var query = from tuple in firstTupleList.Concat(secondTupleList)
                            group tuple.Item2 by tuple.Item1 into g
                            select Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.Aggregate((x, y) => x * y));
```

This does the multiplication for dog and cat, but rat is still in the list which is wrong.

Comment: ok, go ahead and try.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Are the tuples guaranteed to be ordered by key?

Comment: No the order is not guaranteed. I have edited the original list to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    List<Tuple<string, int>> list = new List<Tuple<string, int>>();
    list.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int>("dog", 25));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int>("dog", 10));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int>("cat", 5));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int>("cat", 7));
    list.Add(Tuple.Create<string, int>("other", 4));

    Dictionary<string, int> dic = list.
     GroupBy(t => t.Item1).
     Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1).
     ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key,
                  grp => grp.Select(tuple => tuple.Item2).Aggregate((a, b) => a * b));
```

Comment: This gives me the same result as my approach. The tuple containing "other", 4 is still in the list which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(t => t.Item1)
              .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
              .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, g.Skip(1).Aggregate(g.First().Item2, (i,j) => i*j.Item2)))
              .ToList();

var total = grouped.Sum(i => i.Item2);
```

Comment: You can also drop the Tuple creation and the ToList() if you want. `var result = tuples.GroupBy(x => x.Item1).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Aggregate(1, (acc, t) => acc * t.Item2)).Sum();`